# Why does Qt Creator need a kit for non-qt cmake project

Tags: qt-creator

I selected a Non-Qt C++ project from File->New, and then CMake for the build system, yet Qt Creator still insists that I specify a Qt kit.

I know for qmake projects you need a kit for the qmake, but why does it need it for cmake? The project itself won't use qt or qmake, I just want to use Qt Creator as the IDE. Also would specifying a kit make a dependency on Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to have kits in Qt Creator with or without Qt, with or without a C++ compiler, with or without cmake binaries, etc.

Qt Creator uses kits as a collection of things that are used together in (multiple) projects, so that you do not have to define these same settings again and again. The settings available in a kit depend on the plugins you have enabled and Creator is perfectly happy if some information is not set -- as long as this information is not needed by the project you are working on. So if you open a qmake-based project, creator will complain if a kit has no Qt version set (which is what provides the qmake binary). If you try to open a cmake-based project, then Creator will complain about Kits without a cmake binary set up. Kits are in no way limited to qmake projects, but does also apply to cmake, autotools, nim, python projects (and whatever else is supported;-).

For CMake projects the Kit defines the cmake binary to use, the Generator to use with that binary, default values to pass to cmake, the compiler used by the code model built into Qt Creator (and by the cmake project itself in newer Qt Creator versions), the Qt version that is used by the code model (and by the cmake project in newer QtC versions), the default environment the project will see when building and some more things.